# BackSpace in .bash file

Tags: bash

I work with .bash script and I try to  remove lines from file

```
 sed -e s/^DNS1.*/''/g -i $DNS_IP_CONFIG_FILE
```

but remains blank lines.I need baskspace in this code

Comment: I don't think sed can be used to remove lines completely. But, perhaps something like `sed -z -e s/^DNS1[^\n]*\n]//g -i $DNS_FILE`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sed -i '/^DNS1.*/d' $DNS_IP_CONFIG_FILE
```

Answer (score 5):

```
sed -i -e '/^DNS1/d' "$DNS_IP_CONFIG_FILE"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -i -ne '/^DNS1.*/!p' $DNS_IP_CONFIG_FILE
```